# What is going on with this exposed operator on my view of files?

Tags: views, files

### What I did:

1. Edited a View of Files
2. Added File:usage:entity ID as a filter
3. Exposed the filter
4. Exposed the operator
5. Selected an option and applied it.

I see these weird empty boxes appear below the Entity ID filter, but *only in preview mode*. When I save the view and use the filter on the actual view page, the boxes below the entity ID list don't appear.

[image]

Has anyone else seen this? What causes it?

Comment: I've seen this before but not with a file view (can't remember exactly what it was, maybe a solr search). What CSS IDs do the rogue textfields have? Might help to narrow down exactly which filter is producing them

Comment: They're coming from the Entity ID filter. They appear in $form['id'] (not to be confused with $form_id) for that filter.